# Linking to a PDF in Ionic 1 is slow on iOS (and fast on Android)

Tags: ionic-framework, content-security-policy

It takes 2 to 3 seconds to pull down a PDF from my web server in my Ionic 1 app on Android.  It takes about 45 seconds to get the same PDF on iOS.  Android was this slow as well - then I added `gap://ready file://*` to the content security policy and that made android fast again. So, two questions:

1. Is there a corresponding iOS content security policy key that I'm missing?
2. Why would adding something to the content security policy make downloading a file faster (instead of just making it available or not available)?

For reference, here's my entire content security policy:

```
content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';img-src *  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:"
```